# Android NDK Debug Library

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, adb

I have a Java Android application project that includes a *so* library in libs/armeabi folder.
The c++ code of this library is in a different Android NDK project and is dependent on other different library NDK projects.
Is it possible to debug the c++ code of this library while the Java Android application is running?

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug the native code in .so, first you need .so that was generated with debugging mode. (e.g., NDK_DEBUG = 1)
If you don't have source code and therefore no debuggable .so, there is no way to debug.

Also, please specify your environment such as Android NDK version, IDE, etc.

Assuming you are using Eclipse, **[this](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/07/debugging-android-native-applications.html)** is detailed description how to debug native applications.